# how to do this in regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm building an app with several languages.

```
test.com/ -english index
test.com/ca - canadian english index
test.com/canada-promo - english version of canada promo page
test.com/ca/canada-promo - canadian english version of promo page
```

how would I filter this?

sorry about that. there are actually 4 languages (/fr/ and /es/). I want to be able to determine the language from the url that is passed.

Comment: Don't bother, we read English just fine.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  What are you trying to match using regex?

Comment: sorry about that. there are actually 4 languages /fr/ and /es/ I want to be able to determine the language from the url that is passed.

Comment: OK obviously you have to be able to make a distinction between what's a page name and what's a language, or else you're going to end up enumerating all possible languages in your regex.  Can we assume that any exactly two-letter combination occurring after `test.com/` is a language?  Or are you hoping to have a page "xr" e.g.?

Comment: I only have /es/ /ca/ /fr/  (hopefully) to filter out. The problem that I'm having is if the url starts with the same 2 letters with the one of the languages ie. /fr/ - /french-promo/

Comment: This is tagged php, but probably you want to use mod-rewrite or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.com/(?:([a-z]{2})(?=$|/))?(?:/)?(.*)`

Explanation:

```
test.com/  #match beginning boilerplate, replace with "^" if need be
(?:([a-z]{2})(?=$|/))?  #match two characters if followed by the end of line or slash
(?:/)? #consume the slash if there was one
(.*)   #the page
```

**Edit**: OK I think this works now.  There may be a more elegant solution though.  First group is the language code, second group is the page.  It works for me with the four inputs you gave.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('^/((ca|fr|es)(/|$))?(.*)$', $url, $matches);
$lang = $matches[2];
if (!$lang) {
  $lang = 'en';
}
$url = $matches[4];
```

Comment: Whoops looks like you fixed yours as I was fixing mine; like mine yours at first failed when the language wasn't followed by a slash.  I like yours better; easier not to use the positive lookahead and just match+consume the slash.